# Can not pass a DBI::DatabaseHandle object as an argument to a ruby gem method

Tags: ruby, rubygems, arguments, dbi

I'm new to ruby so forgive me in advance if this is a silly question. I've googled for answers but nothing relevant comes up and it seems the answer should be obvious.

I'm attempting to pass a DBI::DatabaseHandle as function argument and I'm getting a wrong "number of arguments" error when I run the function. Here's my code...

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dbi'

class CmsTest

    def self.get_dbi_connection(hostname, user, password)
        connection = DBI.connect("DBI:OCI8:" + hostname, user, password)
        return connection
    end

    def self.query(connection, sql)
        puts connection
        puts sql
        begin
            request = connection.prepare("#{query}")
            request.execute
            fetched = []
            request.fetch do |row|
                fetched << row.to_h 
            end 
            request.finish
            return fetched
        rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
            log "An error occurred"
            log "Error code:    #{e.err}"
            log "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
        ensure
        end
    end
end
```

So my code that calls this looks like so...

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cms_test'

connection = CmsTest.get_dbi_connection('foo', 'bar', 'fubar')
CmsTest.query(connection, "<some sql query>")
```

So the first argument is a DBI::DatabaseHandle object and the second is some sql query string. When I run that I get this...

```
`query': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

This even though the *query* signature contains two arguments and and I'm passing the method two arguments. The really weird thing for me is that if I put and *exit* statement anywhere in the method body after the *puts* it will show that the method did indeed receive 2 arguments...

```
#<DBI::DatabaseHandle:0x007fa2a316c9f0>
select licensor_id, licensor_name from cf_licensor
```

I can't make any sense of this. Please help.

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You have a method named `query`:

```
def self.query(connection, sql)
```

and then inside `query` you try to call `query`:

```
request = connection.prepare("#{query}")
# -- method call ---------------^^^^^
```

You probably want to use `sql` there and there's no need for string interpolation:

```
request = connection.prepare(sql)
```